# GAE — Strange instance variable behaviour

Tags: python, google-app-engine

On GAE I'm using `hmac` to produce a signature for an AWS API request. My code was originally this:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import time
import hmac
import base64
from hashlib import sha256 as sha256

class AmazonProductAdvertisingAPI:

    secret_access_key = '...'
    my_hmac = hmac.new(secret_access_key, digestmod=sha256)

    def get_signed_url(self, params):

        ....

        # Sign it
        self.my_hmac.update('GET' + "\n" + server + "\n" + path + "\n" + paramstring)
        urlstring = urlstring + "&Signature=" + \
            urllib.quote(base64.encodestring(self.my_hmac.digest()).strip())

        return urlstring
```

With this, I found that the API request (using the URL given by `get_signed_url`) if and only if the request was a "cold start" for the instance, e.g. after I'd deployed the code and was running it for the first time.

However, subsequent requests failed, with AWS claiming that the signature was invalid. This was resolved by moving `my_hmac` to within the method, so that it was a variable within the method rather than an instance variable within the class.

```
...
def get_signed_url(self, params):
    my_hmac = hmac.new(self.secret_access_key, digestmod=sha256)
    ...
```

I have one question: why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `my_hmac` variable was a class variable; one shared by *all* instances of the class.

This means that for every call to `.get_signed_url()` the `self.my_hmac.update()` call would *add* data to the digest, across instances, globally to the application.

Since you only want to calculate the digest for one string only, (the `"GET ..."` string) and not for all strings cumulatively, you *must* create a new `hmac` object for each new digest you want to calculate.

Note the [documentation for the .update()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.update):

> Update the hash object with the string arg. Repeated calls are equivalent to a single call with the concatenation of all the arguments: `m.update(a); m.update(b)` is equivalent to `m.update(a+b)`.

Comment: Doh! First time using Python.

Comment: So, that's a class variable. How do I create instance variables? Within __init__?

Comment: Within `__init__`, yes. Anything within a method that assigns to `self.someattribute` is setting instance variables.

Comment: You're welcome! Note that in this specific case, you want to use a local variable, and not a instance variable; you don't want to calculate the digest of `GET ... 1` + `GET ... 2` + `GET ... 3` either.